# Change Order on X-Axis for Matplotlib chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I created a chart in matplotlib using python and the x-axis is the days of the week (Mon-Sun). When the data was plotted though, the x-axis is not arranged Mon-Sun.

Is there  way I can re-order the x-axis to have it be formatted this way?

or is there a way I can re-order the dataset? It is a csv file that is being read using the panda dataframe

Example Data: (lives in csv: './data/Days_Summary.csv')

```
Day         Value

 Monday      56        
 Tuesday     23    
 Wednesday   34     
 Thursday     56     
  Friday      58     
 Saturday     70      
  Sunday      43
```

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('./data/Days_Summary.csv')
days_values=df.groupby(['day'])['day'].count().plot(kind='bar')
plt.xlabel('Day')
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please show your code, and provide example data if possible.

Comment: Your df has the column `Day` but your code uses `day`.

Answer (score 13):

Use `.loc` to set the day order:

```
field = "Day"
day_order = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
ax = df.set_index(field).loc[day_order].plot(kind="bar", legend=False)
ax.set_ylabel("Value")
```

[image: plot]

Note: Using `groupby()` and `count()` will not give you the values in the `Value` field, but will instead count the number of rows in each group.  In this case, you'll just get a count of 1 for each day. Hence this answer assumes that 
you actually want to plot the values in `Value` for each day.

Comment: What's the meaning of `field = "Day"`?

Comment: Looks like I had meant to pass `field` into `set_index()`.  Good catch, I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 4):

For application on Seaborn. You can do this using count plot https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html

```
day_order = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
sns.countplot(x = "Day", data = df, order = day_order)
```