# How to sort x axis in sns.lineplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I would have a following code that generates this lineplot:

[image]
But I would like to sort x axis to have `1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`. Moreover, I need to have 0 in the 4/5 between 3 and 4. I tried this:

df_sort = df.sort_values(
"ab_test",
key=lambda col: col.map(
{
"0": 14, # see how I insert 0 between 3 and 4
"1": 0,
"2": 5,
"3": 10,
"4": 15,
"5": 20,
"6": 25,
"7": 30,
"8": 35,
"9": 40,
}
),
)

But when I try to plot it using:

```py
sns.lineplot(x="ab_test", y="count", data=abtest_sort, hue="cena_percentil")
```

it gives me the same result as before. How can I fix it, please?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why have an x-axis with an order "1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9"? What kind of data has that order?

Comment: @9769953 these numbers stand for ID and test with ID 0 was done after test number 3.

Comment: Since the numbers are ID, you'll need to handle them as categorical data. I'm not directly sure how that is done best, but that may give you a keyword to search on. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255746/change-order-on-x-axis-for-matplotlib-chart) is somewhat related, and has an answer that involves Seaborn, not just Matplotlib.

Comment: Ah, I see now: your numbers are actually strings. Confusing on the plot itself, but otherwise, that makes sense.

Comment: Could you add a dataframe as code that contains the actual data (or some of it)? That is easier to create an answer.